# Why does my asp.net website asks to save a solution file before quitting?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Whenever i create a website project, before quitting the visual studio, it always asks to save a solution file. Now that i've saved the solution,Every time i open a website, it goes under a solution! can someone help me? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you save the Solution(`.sln`) file, it will reopen under that same solution. You can also reopen your project by directly double-clicking the `solution` file. The solution is just a container for the projects and so there is nothing wrong if your project goes under a solution.

Comment: Yeah but my question is why does a website goes into solution if we choose a stand alone website and not a solution for a project?